# Android: downgrade the image bitmap quality to make activity loads faster

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

First, I'm a newbie in Android.This question may be stupid. Bear with me please.

My activity loads lots of pictures taken by the user(external), and display them in thumbnail(small size picture) in a listView or HorizontalScrollView. I wonder is there any good way to make the bitmap loads faster? I used the bitmapFactory.insampleSize to scale it down. Will the inDensity help? Any other good ways?

I'm thinking about saving a low quality copy for each image, so every time the application will display the thumbnail low quality image unless the user really wants to see the original one. Is that applicable? If so, any approaches?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyway you scale one after you have loaded one and it is the loading that consumes most of the time. If you show circular progress bar while you are still loading then perhaps user will be happy

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to create the scale-down version of your bitmap. Please follow http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap to understand how to have scale-down version of your bitmap. As it is scale-down version of your bitmap to display thumbnails, it will ofcourse save your memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for response. I did scale down the bitmap using insampleSize, but it still takes a fair amount of time.

Comment: If you carefully check the link, it first calculate inSampleSize depending on required height and width. So, first decodeResource is called just to check dimensions (check, options.inJustDecodeBounds is set to true first time). Next time when it call decodeResource, options.inJustDecodeBoundsis set to false.

It work very well as I myself have used it for heavy images which was throwing OOM exceptions. Share your code if possible.